# Understanding invalid literal error for web scraping

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape from Wikipedia the Billboard top 100 for the years 1992 to 2014, and then clean the data. I get an "invalid literal" error at the end:

```
years = range(1992,2015)
yearstext = dict()
for year in years:
    t_1992=requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_Year-End_Hot_100_singles_of_%(year)s' % {"year":year})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(t_1992.text, "html.parser")
    yearstext[year]=soup

def parse_year(year, ytextdixt):
    rows = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "wikitable"}).find_all("tr")[1:]
    cleaner = lambda r: [r[0].get_text(), int(r[1].get_text()), r[2].get_text(), r[2].find("a").get("href"), r[3].get_text(),r[3].find("a").get("href")]
    fields = ["band_singer", "ranking", "song", "songurl","titletext","url"]
    songs = [dict(zip(fields, cleaner(row.find_all("td")))) for row in rows]

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Pharrell Williams'
```

Anyone know the reason why this is?

Comment: The data in column 1 doesn't contain the ranking, it contains the band/singer. But looking at the page, that doesn't seem to be the case. Maybe there is more than one table on the page, and you are getting up the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

'r[1].get_text()' returns 'Pharrell Williams' in some circumstances

then 'int(r[1].get_text())' triggered this exception.

so recheck the details you got from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little experimentation I found that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

year = 1992
t_1992=requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_Year-End_Hot_100_singles_of_%(year)s' % {"year":year})
soup = BeautifulSoup(t_1992.content, "lxml.parser")
rows = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "wikitable"}).find_all("tr")[1:]
rows[0].get_text()
```

Gives:

```
u'\n1\n"End of the Road"\nBoyz II Men\n'
```

So using:

```
rows[0].get_text().strip().split('\n')
```

gives:

```
[u'1', u'"End of the Road"', u'Boyz II Men']
```

that should get you on the right track.

Comment: Didn't realize the pun at the end until I re-read the answer - but I quite like it so leaving it!